# Drawing some simple pictures with tikz

Tags: draw

I've never drawn plots in Latex before and I'm really struggling at drawing some simple pictures with the tikz package. Can anybody help me? The two lines in the second and fourth quadrant should be made perpendicular to the vectors 
x_{.3} and x_{.1} respectively. 
[image]

Comment: You can use relative radial coordinates such as `\draw[->] (3,3) -- ++(30: 2);`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you started:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb]
    \draw[fill=black](105:1.6)--(285:0.6)-| cycle; % filled triangle
    \draw[orange](105:1.8)--(285:0.8);
    \draw[thick](0,2)node[above]{Security 2}--(0,0)--(2,0)node[right]{Security 1};
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {15,45,75} {
      \draw[->](0,0)--(\x:1.8);
      \node at (\x:2){$x_{\xi}$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**
You can make the labels smaller by for example, ad `\small` to the labels. YOu can make the whole picture bigger by adding `scale=3` to the `tikzpicture environment -- there's also`xscale`and`yscale` if you want to scale by different factors in the x and y directions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb,scale=3]
    \draw[fill=black](105:1.6)--(285:0.6)-| cycle; % filled triangle
    \draw[orange](105:1.8)--(285:0.8);
    \draw[thick](0,2)node[above]{\small Security 2}--(0,0)--(2,0)node[right]{\small Security 1};
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {15,45,75} {
      \draw[->](0,0)--(\x:1.8);
      \node at (\x:2){$x_{\xi}$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. How can I make the axes labels smaller? And how can I make my picture bigger?

Comment: @Nenne See my edit

Comment: Thank you! How can I add a vector perpendicular to one of the vectors drawn with foreach?